# How can I implement google web authentication in ionic3 without using platforms?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Iam working in `ionic3` with `Firebase` integration.Here I need to add google web authentication in the login page.Using `cordova` & `ionic-native` google authentication can be implemented for android & ios apps but I need to implement authentication for web in `ionic3`. How can I implement this one?
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase site has the examples, and select web instead of iOS or Android to get to them.  There is also [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) from a quick Google search.